# jQuery toggle table row on click on a specific td

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

So, i have a table with some hidden rows with `class="mov"` that I would like to toggle when you click on a specific td with `id="line"` or `class="line"`.

```
<table align="center" id="editabletable">
<tr class="sinaledit">
<td align="center" id="line" class="line" colspan="9"> 
<table><tr><td id="+" align="center"> + </td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center" >text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
</tr></table></td>
<td align="center" id="x" class="x">x</td>

<tr class="mov">
<td align="center">Card</td>
<td align="center">Type</td>
<td align="center">Code</td>
<td align="center">Desc</td>
<td align="center">P1</td>
<td align="center">P2</td>
<td align="center">P3</td>
<td align="center">P4</td>
<td align="center">P5</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here's the jQuery function:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr.sinaledit').click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.mov'+this.id).toggle('slow');
        });
    $('tr[class^=mov]').hide().children('td');
});
```

It works, but it toggles the rows when you click on any td, even the x one. The x td will have another delete function associated with it, that's why I don't want it do be part of the toggle. But I can't manage to make the toggle when you click only on `id="line"`. Sorry, I'm a jQuery beginner.

Here's a fiddle for demo:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekp2qyqj/1/)

Thank you very much!

Comment: You've got some basic syntax issues but here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sou1z5oy/) to get you started. Change your selector to ` $('tr.sinaledit td#line')` and use `.closest()` to get the `tr` element again.

Comment: It's hard to tell how to get the relation between `.line` and the `.mov` entries right, as there are syntax errors in the HTML of that table. You should fix the markup first and then post it above…

Answer (score 0):

you have simply to attach the click event on the required element.In your case the element has the  id `line` so you have to use the `#` selector to select this element:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#line').click(function(){ 
            $('tr.sinaledit').siblings('.mov').toggle('slow');
        });
    $('tr[class^=mov]').hide().children('td');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" id="editabletable" class="table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" border="1">
<tr class="sinaledit">
<td align="center" id="line" class="line" colspan="9"> 
<table><tr><td id="+" align="center"> + </td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center" >text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
</tr></table></td>
<td align="center" id="x" class="x">x</td>
    
<tr class="mov">
<td align="center">Card</td>
<td align="center">Type</td>
<td align="center">Code</td>
<td align="center">Desc</td>
<td align="center">P1</td>
<td align="center">P2</td>
<td align="center">P3</td>
<td align="center">P4</td>
<td align="center">P5</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
    
<tr class="mov">
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: The HTML is basically wrong, also it's not the best idea to have ID name `+`, at least for [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)

Comment: You're right but I didn't actually noticed I just answered the question how the attach the click event on the required element.

Answer (score 0):

It's really just a matter of how you use your selectors.  I chose to only apply the click event on anything with the '.line' class instead.

Made some changes but see the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uog7cjy8/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.line').on('click', function(){
        // Find the nearest element with .line class
        // Once found, move up to the parent <tr> to find siblings
        // Note: this only works with your current structure
        $(this).closest('.line').parent().siblings('.mov').toggle();
    });

    $('tr[class^=mov]').hide().children('td');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the html structure I like more this

```
<style>
.mov {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<table align="center" id="editabletable">
<tr>
    <td id="add">+</td>
    <td id="remove">x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
</tr>

<tr class="mov">
    <td align="center">Card</td>
    <td align="center">Type</td>
    <td align="center">Code</td>
    <td align="center">Desc</td>
    <td align="center">P1</td>
    <td align="center">P2</td>
    <td align="center">P3</td>
    <td align="center">P4</td>
    <td align="center">P5</td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For the jquery part, this is more simple:

```
$(function() {
 $('#add').click(function(){
         $('.mov').show('slow');
     });
 $('#remove').click(function(){
    $('.mov').hide('slow');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(function() {
    $('.sinaledit').click(function(){
            $('.mov').toggle('slow');
        });
    $('tr[class^=mov]').hide().children('td');
});
```

This will help fixing your need.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekp2qyqj/3/)***

You cannot sibling `<tr>` and `<td>`, `TD` should always be child of `TR`.
It's good to avoid `"+"` as ID name selector.
If you plan to have multiple buttons - simply remove all of your ID and rely on CLASSes.

Here's an example with even **multiple tables:**

```js
$(function() {
  
    $('.table').on("click", ".line", function(){
      
        $(this).siblings('.mov').toggle(800);
      
      }).on("click", ".delete", function(){
      
        $(this).closest("table").fadeOut(function(){
         $(this)/*the table*/.remove();
        });
      
    });
  
});
```

```css
.line:hover {
 background-color:#cf5;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.table { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.table td,
.table th{
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #444;
}
.table tr.mov{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tr class="line"> 
        <td class="show">+</td>
        <td>1 text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td class="delete">x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mov">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Card</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Desc</td>
        <td>P1</td>
        <td>P2</td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>P4</td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mov">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="table">
    <tr class="line"> 
        <td class="show">+</td>
        <td>2 text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td class="delete">x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mov">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Card</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Desc</td>
        <td>P1</td>
        <td>P2</td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>P4</td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mov">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `</tr>` tag corresponding to the `<tr class="sinaledit">` tag so the browser is applying the behavior to all `td` tags.  Try the following:

```
<table align="center" id="editabletable">
<tr class="sinaledit">
<td align="center" id="line" class="line" colspan="9"> 
<table><tr><td id="+" align="center"> + </td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center" >text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
<td align="center">text</td>
</tr></table></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" id="x" class="x">x</td></tr>

<tr class="mov">
<td align="center">Card</td>
<td align="center">Type</td>
<td align="center">Code</td>
<td align="center">Desc</td>
<td align="center">P1</td>
<td align="center">P2</td>
<td align="center">P3</td>
<td align="center">P4</td>
<td align="center">P5</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There are other style edits I would make to make the html easier to follow, but the above is the bare minimum you need to get the desired functionality.

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekp2qyqj/2/)